# Where should I add the N function in my formula in excel 2019?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2019

```
=((MAX(0,L2-5))+J2)*16.25
```

Above is my current formula that calculates pricing. I wanted to have the L column also accept N/A as 0, but I keep getting an error or that I have too many applications.

Tried

```
=N(L2),((MAX(0,L2-5))+J2)*16.25
```

this led to excel suggesting

```
=N(L2)*((MAX(0,L2-5))+J2)*16.25
```

which would make everything zero

Comment: `=(MAX(0,IFERROR(L2-5,0))+J2)*16.25`